# Cannot add an exchange acount on outlook 2016 for OSX El capitan

Tags: macos, email, exchange-server, osx-elcapitan, outlook-2016

Hi,
I recently install office 2016 on my macbook pro late 2011, osx El capitan
I'd like to add my exchange account to the outlook

my domaine is @ofsl.ie
well I add the email and the password and I click on add acount
I got message error that say: outlook for mac cannot add this type of account, to open your account please open your browser and open a session office 365 and then use outlook web app.

any help please

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the server url manually, below link can explain little better

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2016-macoutlook/cannot-add-office-365-email-account-in-outlook-for/a4073328-28d8-4552-9896-654c341a43f9?auth=1